# How do rails development and production database environments work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, dev-to-production

I have a database that I created and populated using the development environment in Rails 3.2.  I deployed the database onto a server using git and phusion passenger.  Currently the server is still running the development database because it is the one that is populated.  I have 2 questions:

1)  If I switch the server to the production environment, will all of my data transfer over? If not, how to I transfer the current data into the production database?

2)  If I push updates to the server from my personal machine using the development database, and the server is using the production database, will all of the data that has been inputted into the production database by users stay in tact? or do I have to configure it to not erase data when I pull my project to the server from git?

Answer (score 2):

**For the first question**:

If you change the environment to production, it will use the database which is configured in `config/database.yml` file. You can take a backup of the development database and import the backup file if you want to use the same database in production.

**For the second question**:

By the term **push updates to the server from my personal machine**, i assume you are talking about code changes being pushed and not any db related things. pull/push operations with git will never affect the way you interact with database. The data from users in production db will remain intact.

Comment: Currently, when I run `git push origin master` on my personal machine, and then go over and run `git pull origin master` on my server machine, it does include all of the data that i've inputted on my personal machine.

Comment: code push and pull are independent of environment, if you push the code from local to git. git pull from server will merge the code without considering the environment of both local or remote server

Answer (score 0):

**1) If I switch the server to the production environment, will all of my data transfer over? If not, how to I transfer the current data into the production database?**

It will not generally by default. The database.yml file has a group for development, testing, and production. Development and Testing will tend to be local, and production (hopefully) is not going to be on your local machine.

**2) If I push updates to the server from my personal machine using the development database, and the server is using the production database, will all of the data that has been inputted into the production database by users stay in tact? or do I have to configure it to not erase data when I pull my project to the server from git?**

The actual data should stay in tact, however, remember to make your migrations compatible with the data that is up there. One big thing to watch out for here is adding a mandatory field to an existing table without dealing with repopulating earlier records. This will break your deployment.

You can get the database from production/send it back by using your environment's resources (I think Heroku uses [pg:dump](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)).

WRT your comment on GhostRider's answer, are you using the production DB remotely from development?/Where is your deployment? What does your database.yml file look like? (remember to not include your passwords :D, I will update answer on reply).

Comment: I'm deploying to a linux machine that is just being used on a local network where I work.  I have not changed the .yml file from default: production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000 `

Comment: Try adding the db file to .gitignore